# how to use Cytoscape from igraph

Tags: r, cytoscape

How can we reflect Fruchterman-Reingold layout using Cytoscape?
I cannot replicate the Fruchterman-Reingold layout figure from igraph using Cytoscape.

```
 library(RCy3)
 library(igraph)
 library(ggraph)
 library(tidygraph)
 library(RColorBrewer)

actors <- data.frame(name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Cecil", "David",
                        "Esmeralda"),
                 age=c(48,33,45,34,21),
                 gender=c("F","M","F","M","F"))
relations <- data.frame(from=c("Bob", "Cecil", "Cecil", "David",
                           "David", "Esmeralda"),
                    to=c("Alice", "Bob", "Alice", "Alice", "Bob", "Alice"),
                    same.dept=c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),
                    weight=c(4,5,5,2,1,1), advice=c(4,5,5,4,2,3))
 ig <- graph_from_data_frame(relations, directed=F, vertices=actors)

coul  <- brewer.pal(2, "Set1") 
my_color <- coul[as.numeric(as.factor(V(ig)$gender))]
coords <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(ig)
plot(ig,layout=coords, vertex.color=my_color)


cytoscapePing()


createNetworkFromIgraph(ig,"myIgraph")
layoutNetwork('fruchterman-rheingold gravity_multiplier=1 nIterations=100')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is the correct answer to your question, but I don't think you need to specify `gravity multiplier` in your `layoutNetwork` command. I did not check in detail the `Fruchterman-reingold` algorithm but as I understand your question, you want to apply the same algorithm between `igraph` and `Cytoscape`.

For that, I first take a look at the parameters passed by default to the function `layout.fruchterman.reingold` which is basically calling the function `layout_with_fr` (wrote `layout_with_fr` in R console to see the function parameters).

Checking the code of this function, you can see that based on how you write it, only two parameters are set. The first one is number of iteration (set by default to 500) and the second is the temperature start (start.temp eqault to he sqrt of vcount of your graph). So, here `start.temp = sqrt(5)`.

Then, you can check attributes of the `Fruchterman-reingold` algorithm in Cytoscape by using:

```r
getLayoutPropertyNames("fruchterman-rheingold")

[1] "Available arguments for 'layout fruchterman-rheingold':"
 [1] "attraction_multiplier" "conflict_avoidance"    "defaultEdgeWeight"    
 [4] "edgeAttribute"         "gravity_multiplier"    "layout3D"             
 [7] "max_distance_factor"   "maxWeightCutoff"       "minWeightCutoff"      
[10] "network"               "nIterations"           "nodeAttribute"        
[13] "nodeList"              "randomize"             "repulsion_multiplier" 
[16] "singlePartition"       "spread_factor"         "temperature"          
[19] "type"                  "update_iterations"
```

So, I think based on your example, we should use only `nIterations` and `temperature` arguments:

```r
createNetworkFromIgraph(ig,"myIgraph")
setNodeShapeDefault("ELLIPSE")
setNodeSizeDefault(30)
setNodeColorMapping("gender", c("F","M"), c( "#E41A1C", "#377EB8"), mapping.type = "d")
setLayoutProperties("fruchterman-rheingold", 
                    list(nIterations=500,
                         temperature = sqrt(5)))
layoutNetwork("fruchterman-rheingold")
```

And you get such representation:
[image]

Empirically, I found that if you are using `gravity_multiplier=1`, you need to also pass the argument `repulsion_multiplier = 1` to compensate and make your network more appealing.

Hope it will help you to figure it out the solution to your question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I still cannot replicate in my own data with 100 samples. It looks like Biolayout......

Comment: Sorry to hear that, my knowledge are quite limited on this subject. Maybe you can contact directly developpers of Cytoscape